# Jquery textbox value disable

Tags: jquery

I just wanted to disable both textbox and its value using jquery.

For example:

```
input.disabled = true; 
input.setAttribute('data-hidden-value', input.value); 
input.value = '';
```

In here instead of making `input.value` empty, I wanted to disable it.

Comment: Dear What do u mean by disable value ?

Comment: If you don't want to "make the input.value empty" then just remove that third line.  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To disable an input you need to get the selector of the input and set its property to disabled:

```
$("#inputSelector").prop("disabled", true);
```

**Example Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#theInput").prop("disabled", true);
    });
</script>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input id="theInput" type="text" />
  </body>
</html>
```